# As a frontend how do you work with backend without starting it locally?

Tags: git, frontend, backend, devops

I'm working on a project where frontend and backend people are working apart.

The tech lead would like to work on a per feature branch basis. It would mean that we, as frontends, would have to run the backend locally to test the last updates. Working on different branches mean that backends can merge their code on the main branch ahead on the frontends and will be consummed while deployed, it is still not ideal but frontends wouldn't have to run the backend.

Is there a modern way to prevent the fact that the setup of a backend on different OS can be a pain in the *** and work on the same branch ?

Comment: What does prevent you from mocking server responses so that you could proceed working independently?

Comment: It feels like doing 2 times the job to me but yes it is a possible solution